# Python parsing json data

Tags: javascript, python, json

I was trying to parse a json file and select some attribute.

here is my code

```
import json
import urllib

results = json.load(urllib.urlopen("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/adgmajn2?apikey=L63EvSC1x5vG8iSbm9Jon3784mkDp1Or"))

parse_result  = json.loads(results)
print parse_result
```

And here is json data format

```
{
  "name": "google_test",
  "count": 20,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 1,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Sun Jun 07 2015 17:19:33 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "content": "Parse handles everything you need to store data securely and efficiently in the cloud. Store basic data types, including locations and photos, and query across ...",
        "title": {
          "href": "https://parse.com/products/core",
          "text": "Parse Core | Everything your app needs to save data, be ..."
        },
        "index": 1,
        "url": "https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#/es_th=1&q=pase%20data"
      },
      {
        "content": "Parsing or syntactic analysis is the process of analysing a string of symbols, either ... In order to parse natural language data, researchers must first agree on the  ...",
        "title": {
          "href": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing",
          "text": "Parsing - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"
        },
        "index": 2,
        "url": "https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#/es_th=1&q=pase%20data"
      },
      {
        "content": "In a data flow, Integration Services sources do the work of extracting data, parsing string data, and converting data to an Integration Services data type.",
        "title": {
          "href": "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms141022.aspx",
          "text": "Parsing Data - MSDN - Microsoft"
        }

        ......
    ]
  }
```

However, it show me some error. I can't understand what is it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "get_json_data_2.py", line 6, in 
>           parse_result  = json.loads(results)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in loads
>           return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py",
>   line 365, in decode
>           obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>       TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: as long as your link is correct then json.load(" ") should return a python dict and you can parse through it using key values.

Answer (score 8):

`results` already contains the parsed JSON tree. You don't need the `loads` part:

```
import json
import urllib

results = json.load(urllib.urlopen("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/adgmajn2?apikey=L63EvSC1x5vG8iSbm9Jon3784mkDp1Or"))

print results
```

Comment: Thanks, you have been a great help! I got it.

Answer (score -3):

You could convert json to yaml using for example this: http://jsontoyaml.com/ . Yaml is python "version" of json.

```
import yaml

stram = open("test", "r")
print yaml.load(stram)
```

Comment: what the heck does: "Yaml is python version of json." mean?  That's nonsense.

Comment: um, but why I need to convert to `yaml` ? Doesn't normal `json` type work in python? Actually, I need to pass `json` file from other script. So, I am afraid of the error of type.

Comment: the OP is asking about parsing JSON with the standard library's json module.  Your answer makes no sense and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: yaml support isn't even built in... json is.